# Local Call Classification in CDR records from Cisco CallManager

Tags: cisco, telephony, call-manager

I am trying to analyze our telephone usage to evaluate our phone plan with our PRI provider.

I have enabled CDR records within Call Manager and am able to generate "Gateway Summary" reports which appears to create a report of total number of calls in each "Call Classification" group (On Net, Internal, Local, Long Distance, International, Incoming, Tandem, Others). Everything seems to be properly identified except local calls. Local Calls are being classified as Long Distance Calls.

I am generating the report by going to the CDR Analysis and Reporting Utility, and choosing Device Reports -> Gateway -> Summary and selecting all Call Types.

How can I change the classification for local calls so they are identified properly?

From my initial research, it seems that the Route Pattern is treating local calls like long distance calls. This seems to "work" because our region requires 10 digit dialing for local calls, but is potentially wrong and causing this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted Cisco TAC support, and they were able to track this down:

1. Log into the Cisco CallManager Serviceability page.
2. In the Tools menu, choose CDR Analysis and Reporting
3. From the System menu, choose System Parameters, then choose Dial Plan Configuration

The filters/patterns defined here will drive the classifications used in the reports. My settings had overlapping patterns, so local calls were being classified as Long Distance calls. Editing the patterns to remove the overlap results in proper classifications.